# Filetransfer plugins fails on phonegap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, file-transfer

Adding the plugin FileTransfer to config.xml fails on phonegap-build for android.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" version="1.3.0"/>
```

I saw an answer relating to cordova build. But how should I resolve the issue for phonegap build?
It has always been working until today (or maybe yesterday). What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cordova-plugin-file-transfer` installs `cordova-plugin-file` too, and the latest version of `cordova-plugin-file` doesn't support phonegap build because it requires cordova android 5.0.0 that isn't on phonegap build, so install yourself the `cordova-plugin-file` with the previous version, add this line before the `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` one

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" version="3.0.0"/>
```

this is going to be reverted soon, so it shouldn't be a problem in a few hours

Comment: Awesome. Just saw your same comment in phonegap build forum. What do you mean by in few hours? Would android 5.0.0 automatically be used by phonegap cli-5.2.0? Or do I still need to update the phoengap-version later on.

Comment: phonegap build install the version of the plugin tagged as "latest" if you don't set a version, so changes are being made right now to make the "latest" point to the previous version of the plugin instead of the real latest version and you won't need to add the file plugin as I told you. I think cordova android 5.0.0 will be added soon, but it will take at least a few days.